# More than one workbook object in project explorer

Tags: vba, excel

I have this strange problem. I have a vba project, where the project explorer displays more than one workbook object. It is exactly the same as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273071/excel-vba-project-has-generated-multiple-workbook-objects) SO question, but I don't have any faulty references to uncheck.

However, I do know what's caused it and I'm sure you can all duplicate. What I did was use the codename for a sheet as a byref argument for a simple sub and at the end of the sub, nulled the worksheet object. So I nulled the whole sheet through the reference.

Something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_1()
    test_2 sh:=Sheet2
End Sub

Sub test_2(ByRef sh As Worksheet)
    Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you run test_1, it will run without problems. But after that, the 'Sheet2' codename is invalid. And if you close and reopen the workbook, you'll see what I mean. Excel creates a new worksheet with the same name (but another CodeName). Any data stored in the cells of the sheet is not lost. The old CodeName references the Workbook Object.

[image: project explorer]

I have not found a way to restore or remove the old references so far (other then move all the objects to a new workbook). I am using Excel 2013.

Solution is of course not so null the worksheet, but does anyone have any idea how to restore?

Comment: Do you have another Excel workbook open?  They will both display in the same code editor.

Comment: @roryap Yes I do. And several global templates. But I tested this sample above also on an 'empty' excel instance. Both show the same.

Comment: How about just deleting the sheet at the same time using: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False
sh.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Comment: @Luuklag not sure what you mean by 'at the same time'? Deletion (right click I'm the explorer) is not possible.

Comment: @Luuklag oh, like that. Not sure what that would do. Nulling the sheet is simply a mistake, it was not my intention. However deleting the sheets now the problem exists is not possible

Comment: @Jzz does your code really require `sh` to be set to `Nothing` otherwise you could just do without the line in future cases, to avoid this as well. As VBA has its own garbage collection.

Comment: @Luuklag Although it is good practice to do so, and I make a point of always doing so, nulling a ByRef argument / parameter does not make much sense (perhaps there are exemptions). But as I said: it was a mistake and I removed the line already.

Comment: no "solution" or at least an explanation of why does this happens? I'm having the same isuue and I'm baffled.

Comment: @pablete, no I never found a solution, other than moving all my code to a new workbook and deleting the old.

Answer (score -2):

Well, after suffering this weird behaviour of Excel I can finally say that I have tried man times and that I can confirm that the cause (at least for my experiments) was indeed using User Defined Functions (UDFs). There is no way of fixing a Workbook once the extrange sheets appear. My approach was to just create a new Workbook and copy all the Modules and all the sheets from the old (broken) one.

Just make sure to **not** use user defined functions if you are having this issue.

Comment: I'm wondering why was this answer downvoted but no alternative answer was provided. At least a reason for the downvote would be apreciated, we all could learn something from it.