# Location of excel vba macros in xml

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have a .xlsm format excel (2013) spreadsheet (containing vba macros) that I wish to convert to .xml (to save in a non-proprietary format in a repository, and to provide version control e.g. automated merging of branches in git).

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984254/how-to-view-the-xml-form-of-an-excel-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082278/how-to-properly-assemble-a-valid-xlsx-file-from-its-internal-sub-components), `.xlsx` files are zipped `xml`, so they can be  converted by simply unzipping.

I tried this with a macro-enabled `.xlsm` file, and I do get an `xml` structure of the spreadsheet. But I can't find the macros anywhere. Does anyone know where the macros are stored in `.xlsm` and where to find them in the corresponding unzipped folder.

Comment: For "version control", I usually just export the VBA modules and then store those text files.  Not ideal, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you unzip the `*.xslm` you will find a `/xl/vbaProject.bin` within the ZIP archive. This is the binary file which contains the macros.