# Error 429 "Activex component can't create object" when copying Cells to new worksheet Column

Tags: excel, vba

This code copies columns P & Q from each worksheet and posts them to a new worksheet consolidated. It also deletes all blank cells.

The code works on a very small file but isn't producing the same results on the new workbook.

ALL COLUMNS from previous "small workbook" to new workbook are the same. The only thing that changed is the number of worksheets which is 650.

I get a runtime error 429 "Activex component can't create object".

```
Sub merge()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet, ShM As Worksheet, i&, z&
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Set Sh = Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    Sh.Name = "consolidated"
    For Each ShM In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ShM.Name <> Sh.Name Then
            i = ShM.Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row
            z = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            While (z > 1) And (Sh.Cells(z, 2).Value = "")
                z = z - 1
            Wend
            ShM.Activate: ShM.Range(Cells(1, 16), Cells(i, 17)).Copy
            Sh.Activate: Sh.Cells(z, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next ShM
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is not caused by the code you've posted, please see this:
[You receive run-time error 429 when you automate Office applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828550)

also this issue has been discussed here:

[Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327327/run-time-error-429-activex-component-cant-create-object-vba)

check **tools~>references** for the missing components

Comment: tools > references is greyed out for me. Would you know why?

Comment: @Salih I've guessing it because you trying to go into references during debugging mode >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhwzC.png

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue 4 years later, my VBA code literally failed on the very first two lines:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
```

Same error if I use ?ThisWorkbook.name in the immediate window, etc. No matter what I do, I cannot use the "ThisWorkbook" object in this particular .xlsm

I created a brand new workbook, saved it as .xslm and copied the entire module to the new book, bingo, works perfectly.

There doesn't seem to be any difference between the new book I created and the old book that doesn't work...

tools->references are identical, they were saved on the same machine, same version of excel, etc etc.

It's just a bizzare issue that I can't figure out the cause of, in this particular Workbook, the "ThisWorkbook" function is broken. Re-creating the workbook from scratch seems to resolve it, but it's a poor solution.

Comment: i get the error for the exact same line you mentioned. did you find any better fix ?