# Create new worksheet code is no longer working

Tags: excel, vba

I created a vba macro a while ago for work. For me it has always run but recently others have found that my code runs into an error when creating a new sheet with a specific name. The error is "ActiveX component can't create object".

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Assessment Stats"
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: 3rd line ```ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))```

Comment: Have you checked if the workbook already has a sheet with that name?

Comment: `The error is "ActiveX component can't create object".` Did you recently install a new ms-office version on an existing version?

Comment: Yeah I've checked that's not the issue. I have multiple macors with that code for different sheets and all have stopped working

Comment: To my knowledge we haven't installed a new version of excel but i'll have to check with IT

Comment: ok check two things for me **[1]** If a new version was installed on an existing version **[2]** If Excel(you as a user) have enough `Rights`. Try this. Ask the IT guy to right click on excel.exe and click on "run as administrator" now try you code. If you do not get the same error then it is "Rights" issue.

Comment: Yeah the same error is coming up for IT, nothing has changed for excel.

Comment: Does it error no matter what name you use?  Do you have an event handler attached to the workbook_newsheet event?  Either in that workbook or in an add-in?  Try setting your error handling preferences to "Break in class module" and see if anything changes.

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430942/error-429-activex-component-cant-create-object-when-copying-cells-to-new-work)

Comment: Break it down. Run `?ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count` in the immediate pane (Ctrl+G), then try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add` (still in the immediate pane) - does it work? Next try `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(3)`, where `3` is the hard-coded value you got from the `.Count` test. Does it work? If the workbook has event handlers for a sheet being created or activated, try `Application.EnableEvents = False` before you add the sheet, and `Application.EnableEvents = True` after -- does it still blow up?