# How to fix "Execution Error 429 : ActiveX can't create object" error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-pdf

This Excel macro below should convert all .Docx into the selected folder to .Pdf

Here is the code line which provide me the error Code 429, But several hours ago this same line of code was working.

```
Documents.Open (filePath & currFile) 'Error Code 429
```

Here the full macro's code

```
Sub ConvertDocxInDirToPDF()

Dim filePath As String
Dim currFile As String

filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
MsgBox filePath
currFile = Dir(filePath & "*.docx")

Do While currFile <> ""

    Documents.Open (filePath & currFile) 'Error Code 429

    Documents(currFile).ExportAsFixedFormat _
        OutputFileName:=filePath & Left(currFile, Len(currFile) - Len(".docx")) & ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=17
    Documents(currFile).Close

    currFile = Dir()

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is there a simple way to make this macro working and to fix this error.

Best regards.

Comment: how are you setting the Documents variable?  Did you have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327327/run-time-error-429-activex-component-cant-create-object-vba?rq=1, perhaps it'll get you going the right direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Documents.Open` is a method of the Documents object, which needs the "MS Word Object Library" to function, without being referred to a word object explicitly:

[image]

What does this mean? If the `Microsoft Word 1X.0` reference is checked (VBE>Extras>Libraries), then the code below works quite ok:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Dim currFile As String
    currFile = Dir(filePath & "*.docx")

    Dim wrdDoc As Object
    Documents.Open filePath & currFile

End Sub
```

If the "MS Word Object Library" is not referred, then with late binding it still could be referred to the object. (Late binding is `CreateObject("Word.Application")`):

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Dim currFile As String
    currFile = Dir(filePath & "*.docx")

    Dim wrdApps As Object
    Set wrdApps = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApps.Documents.Open (filePath & currFile)

End Sub
```

If needed, `Documents.Open` may return a document object:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Dim currFile As String
    currFile = Dir(filePath & "*.docx")

    Dim wrdApps As Object
    Set wrdApps = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Dim wrdDoc As Object
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApps.Documents.Open(filePath & currFile)

End Sub
```

- [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open)

Comment: Thank you @Vityata , Thanks it solved my problem can you explain me why `Documents.open` was working and now this don't. I am trying to understand but i guess i miss something here. Regards

Comment: @Dorian - you are welcome. I have enlarged the answer, explaining the needed library to use `Documents.Open` from Excel, without returning an object.

Comment: Helle, Now I got the same error but here : `Set wrdApps = CreateObject("Word.Application")` Strange fact when i press F5 After the error message the code works well how can I fix this ?

Comment: @Dorian - strange indeed. Try one of these - create the file in a new word file. Then  try one of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343021/macro-stopping-without-breakpoint/40343078#40343078

Comment: @Viyata , Thanks I just dodged the issue by Killing Word process at the end of each subb using docx. Thanks for all